# Are Marbonite tiles good electrical insulator

Tags: electrical, tile, grounding, safety, inverter

I know whenever we handle Circuit breaker or Main Supply lever at home.

We have to wear a footwear which is non-conductive and insulated glove.

My question is , As far as I'm aware a tile which is not wet should be non-conductive too.

It might be worthwhile to invest on EH(Electrical Hazard) shoe for a professional but for a home owner , it's another investment which he's gonna use once in a while

- When tripper got tripped
- When electrical fuse is gone
- When we pour distilled water in inverter battery

So If I don't have a non-conductive electrial hazard footwear . am i free to stand on tile and handle the circuit-breaker ?

FYI:

We're supposed to touch the Circuit breaker unit's cover when main is off. But my parents are sometimes lazy , so when the circuit breaker trips, they just touch the cover to open then turn RCB on before turning off the mains.

[image]

Comment: Most dry floors(except metal) should be relativity safe/non conductive.  The problem is mainly with yours hands near live power and not turning main breaker/fuse off.

Comment: special footware? rubber mud boots should be sufficient,  or even flip-flops if they are new and not squashed thin.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly *why* you have to work on live circuits?

Comment: There is no good reason to work on live circuits at home unless, for example, you have medical equipment critical to keeping someone alive. That is basically it.

Comment: Note that insinuating you feet won't protect you from a hand-to-hand shock. And second the observation that if you need to ask this question you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: _Any_ rubber soled shoe (like a sneaker/tennis shoe/trainer) should provide more than sufficient insulation from the ground.

Comment: Working inside a panel without turning the main breaker/disconnect off is just stupid.  Switching a breaker off/on, you should be protected enough without special wear, since everything dangerous should be covered.

Comment: @crip659 - The problem is my parents are turning on the RCB by accessing the circuit breaker cover. They're supposed to open the cover when they turn off supply from main but they're ignoring it. So I'm thinking to keep a electrical glove besides the Circuit cover. As long as the tile is dry , it should be fine just with a glove right ?

Comment: @FreeMan - Thanks but the tile itself have resistance for electricity right ?

Comment: @keshlam - If we have rubber glove , hand to hand shock should be prevented right ? not sure what should be the thickness to provide enough resistance

Comment: @JonCuster - Sorry I mean Circuit-Breaker unit .. we have to access it when tripper goes off. It's possible the circuit breaker unit might be energised and it might give us shock when we forget to turn the mains supply off

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - Please go through my above comments and updated question. Appreciate it

Comment: @Jasen - any rubber flip-flop will do ? is there any minimum thickness or any particular rubber composition ?

Comment: Panels usually have a door cover to access, to open to open/close, turn on/off the breakers.  There should also be be a screwed on cover behind the door to access the breakers/wires themselves( the shocking stuff).  The breakers parts you can touch from the door should be plastic/electrical insulated.  Open the screw on cover is where you worry.

Comment: @crip659 - As a house owner , I won't deal with the breaker wires .. mostly opening the panel cover to turn on the breaker which went off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment by the OP:

> As a house owner , I won't deal with the breaker wires .. opening the panel cover to turn on the breaker which went off.

Unless there is a *MAJOR* fault in the wiring inside the breaker panel, then you have *nothing* to worry about when turning breakers on/off. If there were such a major fault, you are would have discovered it by now since it sounds like you've turned breakers on/off in this panel before.

So long as you're not being stupid (like holding a bare wire leading into a puddle of water), it doesn't matter what surface you're standing on, what clothing you're wearing, or much of anything else. The "consumer access" portion of a breaker panel is designed to keep you safe from electrical shock.

It's only when you unscrew this cover (so that you can "deal with the breaker wires") that all the extra precautions are necessary. Even then, things mentioned in the comments, like standing on a carpeted floor, wearing rubber soled shoes, etc. are *more* than sufficient.

Unless your floor tiles are ungrounded metal, you have nothing to worry about when turning a breaker on or off.

Comment: I got you point thanks. But just to be clear "Unless your floor tiles are ungrounded metal, you have nothing to worry "  if the floor is ungrounded metal , it offers high resistance right . then there's no electricity shock risk .. am I right ? May be it's not worded properly